# Wordpress Website CSS different in IE&Firefox

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have a Wordpress website that I designed from a template I purchased. support for the template is a bit tough to get so I decided to ask here maybe someone knows the answer to this.

The website layout looks good in Chrome, but weird in IE and Firefox latest ver.

This is the Chrome normal layout:

[image]

And this is in Firefox/IE:

[image]

The code for the website is spread over php files..but this is the start of Header.php

```
    <?php
/**
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage ***  */ 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html <?php language_attributes(); ?>> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>


<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />


<?php if(get_option('header_favicon')) { ?>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo get_option('header_favicon'); ?>" />
<?php } ?>
<title><?php if(is_front_page()) { bloginfo('name'); } else { wp_title( '', true, 'right' ); }?></title>
<?php if(get_option('rss_feed')) { ?>
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="<?php echo get_option('rss_title'); ?>" href="<?php echo get_option('rss_feed'); ?>" />
<?php }
```

Any idea what can solve this?

Comment: Thanks for providing some code, but it's not really relevant - we'd need the relevant parts of HTML+CSS as rendered in the browser. it's hard to tell from an image - could be the _repeat_ setting of the background image.

Comment: im guessing going to the website and firebug it wont help?!

Comment: It's not for _us_ to do it but that's what I'd do to debug it if I were you (developer tools in Chrome/IE may also help compare the different outputs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find this rule in the CSS (line 115)

```
.skinset-header, .skinset-footer, .skinset-main.nv-skin {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent !important;
border: 0.7px solid #E9E9E9 !important;
}
```

Remove the border property.

```
.skinset-header, .skinset-footer, .skinset-main.nv-skin {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent !important;
}
```

You then get a blue line on FF which is here:

```
.skinset-background .accordionhead.ui-accordion-content-active, .skinset-background .ui-state-active, .skinset-background #primary-wrapper.nv-dark .ui-state-active, .skinset-background #nv-tabs ul li ul, #primary-wrapper .skinset-background.sub-menu, .skinset-background span.menu-highlight, .skinset-background #primary-wrapper .skinset-header.nv-skin, .skinset-background div.item-list-tabs ul li.selected, .skinset-background div.item-list-tabs ul li.current, .skinset-background div.item-list-tabs ul li.new, .skinset-background #topic-post-list, .skinset-background table.forum, .skinset-background table.bbp-topics, .skinset-background table.bbp-replies, .skinset-background table.bbp-forums, .skinset-background ul#activity-stream {
border-top: 2px solid #61C4FD;
}
```

In future use Firebug in FireFox - http://getfirebug.com/downloads/, very useful

Comment: Thank you very much richard!! you helped a great deal! usually i use Chrome Inspect Element..but proves firebug is useful ;)

Comment: Can you mark the answer as correct if it solves your problem? I prefer FireBug, you can point at a Div rather than having to drill-down.

Comment: I will mark as correct..but one more q'...if i remove the line you suggested it removes the transparent design i gave it..on all browsers. if it stays then its only visible in chrome and safari. it seems this line is good for me but not for Firefox or IE lol  border: 0.7px solid #E9E9E9 !important;

Comment: Pop it back in temporarily for me

Comment: Struggling to see the difference apart from the big blue line, see answer

Comment: I see..well yeah its just semantics you know...i can handle it manually ;) again..very useful info and thank you buddy :)